# error undefined procedure in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am working with the following knowledge base:

```
house_elf(dobby).
witch(hermione).
witch('McGonagall').
witch(rita_skeeter).
magic(X):-house_elf(X).
magic(X):-wizard(X).
magic(X):-witch(X).
```

and the exercise says: Which of the following queries are satisfied? where relevant, give all the variable instantiations that lead to success. This is the way i answered them:

```
1.?-magic(house_elf).   answer no
2.?-wizard(harry).      answer no
3.?-magic(wizard).      answer no
4.?-magic('McGonagall').answer yes, X= 'McGonagall'
5.?-magic(hermione).    answer yes, X= hermione
```

but if i ask prolog the query, for example:

`?-magic(house_elf).` it says ERROR: magic/1: Undefined procedure: wizard/1 and then throws me an exception: Exception: (7) wizard(house_elf) ? and it is the same for the the 3,4,5th queries, what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the *goal* wizard/1 is not defined.

Recent Prologs attempt to help debugging signalling undefined predicates.
You can avoid the error adding a *directive*

```
:- dynamic(wizard/1).
```